# When ntop is restarted the ntop counter gets reset and all stats are gone

Tags: network-monitoring, ntop

I am using Ntop 3.3-13 to collect statistical data about network usage.

When Ntop is restarted, all counters get reset and Ntop traffic stats page starts showing the output from the beginning.

How can I prevent this from happening? How can I enable persistent storage on Ntop?

Answer (score 4):

No you can not keep the data between restarts. ntop keeps its data in memory and it is lost upon restarts. You can use the rrd files to keep data longer but there is no way to have ntop resume with all of the data it had the last time it was ran.

Maybe try nprobe?

A previous response mentions `-S`, if you check the man page you will see that `-S` is no longer a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ntop/rrdandntop.pdf

Answer (score -1):

From the ntop [FAQ](http://www.ntop.org/faq.txt):

```
Q. I start ntop with "-S 2" in order to store traffic
   statistics. Unfortunately when I restart ntop the
   stats are gone. What's wrong?
A. "-S" enables ntop to store on the disk host traffic statistics. This
   means that is host XYZ was seen by ntop in a previous run, the host
   traffic statistics are stored on disk so that the next time ntop is
   restarted (or if the entry was purged from memory and needs to be
   resurrected) the host information is not empty but the traffic 
   statistics start from the data saved on disk. Note that hosts are 
   resurrected *only* when ntop sees traffic for such hosts. This means 
   that when you restart ntop you *won't* see all the hosts ntop saw when 
   it stopped, but ntop populates its memory as usual with the difference
   that host statistics won't start from scratch but from the saved data.
```

Maybe the -S option works for you?

Comment: -S is not an option in 3.3.

Comment: Your faq link is fully 404 compliant;)

Comment: http://www.ntopsupport.com/faq.html